# Get Files from absolute path on pc in android Project

Tags: android, file, getfiles

I am trying to build a android app where in a part I need to get the containing file names of a specific folder.

```
String DirectoryPath = "D:\\Images";
File Directory = new File (DirectoryPath);
for(File f:Directory.listFiles())
{
   String name = f.getName();
}
```

I am using above code to reach and get files but an Error occurs which is a null pointer exception. I am pretty aware what it means but can not solve my problem either.

Edit: I changed the wrong written words sory for it.

Comment: try to pull that images from your `Computer` to `sdcard` and then access it

Comment: Well, if the folder is too big than it cause a lot more trouble than I am in rigth now..

Comment: Directory and directory are different variable.
File `Directory` = new File (DirectoryPath);
for(File f:`directory`.listFiles())~

Comment: I have written it wrong sory they are same variables.

Comment: You can not access the PC file system from Android, unless the PC has some service that serves the file (for example, a http server).

Comment: @Tato: so do you know anyway to do this? any code snippet maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Your Android device has no visibility into your PC's filesystem.

As others have mentioned, you'll likely want to transfer these files to the device somehow. Putting them on the SD card is a good choice if the files are large.

If that's not an option, you could instead run a WWW or FTP server on your PC and access the files over the network.